# Web Governance Alternatives to Site Improve

Tags: windows, gratis, web-apps, software-development

I am looking for an alternative, for my company's website, to SiteImprove (Web Governance Software). I would like to have the:

- Quality Insurance (Ability to identify broken links and misspellings on our website)
- Analytics
- Response in real time (Monitors web site and all blogs and provides real-time reports on issues such as, website or blogs crash, slow response times, irregular behavior)

These are features I currently have with SiteImprove.

I would like it to be free (ideally) or would be willing to pay subscription fees if they are more cost-effective than SiteImprove (roughly $10,000/yr).

It can be a series of new programs as long as they are reliable or a comprehensive alternative as long as it is less expensive. Thank you so much!!

Comment: It would be preferable to edit your original question ([Alternatives to SiteImprove](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7261/185)) instead of posting a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Little Forest index (LFi) is a Web Governance platform which addresses all areas of Quality Management in one easy to use product.
URL - http://www.littleforest.co.uk/

It covers all your needs, including;
Analytics,
Content e.g. Broken Links & Spelling,
Uptime & Response Times,
Accessibility & more.

Cheaper than all of the tools mentioned above it also includes additional features like;

Single Digital Success Score & Tracking - The platform groups all your data into one easy to digest score, so you can see at a glance how your site is performing and monitor it's progress over time.

Multi-site Bench Marking - This way you can compare your different sites and see which are performing best and use these insights to improve.

Our Digital Team use the tool on a daily basis and the results have been unparalleled. 
They also offer a FREE TRIAL which I recommend - http://www.littleforest.co.uk/contact-us/

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different tools which provide SOME of the features you need. However, as you probably already know, using lots of separate tools for managing a website can really confuse things and reduce efficiency. Since “time is money,” consider how valuable it is for your organization to streamline website management by using one single tool.

As for an affordable tool which does everything you need, I recommend checking out Monsido.

Monsido is an all-in-one Web Governance and Quality Assurance tool suite. It crawls your website once per week (or on-demand) and finds errors and improvement opportunities on the site.

The tool is very powerful, but is designed with user-friendliness in mind. The dashboard is easy to navigate and there are even in-app suggestions on what steps to take to fix errors. In other words, you don’t have to be an expert to use it.

As for costs, Monsido is very affordable. Quality Assurance, SEO Audit, Response Time Monitoring, and Analytics are all included in the price of the Enterprise Plus plan.  If you need to get your website in compliance with Section 508 or WCAG standards, Monsido also offers Web Accessibility testing as a very affordable add-on.

Monsido does have a limited free plan, which you can use to check out the dashboard and the features. If you want the full functionality of the tool though, then you will of course have to sign up for a subscription.

If you want to see how Monsido compares to what you are using now, you can check out:

- http://monsido.com
- http://monsido.com/web-governance-alternative/

Full disclosure: I am the co-founder of Monsido.

Answer (score 0):

Sitemorse is an alternative to SiteImprove, and possibly the most common upgrade. Further to this, if you want to stay with just 'reporting' Sitemorse guarantees to be cheaper, by a minimum of 33%.

Sitemorse is also able to demonstrate a more in depth and thorough capability across additional tests, checks and measures.

One of the unique capabilities of Sitemorse is scalability. Your service can grow with you, initially moving you from a SiteImprove type 'reacting to reports' service to a pro-active management of content with Sitemorse Foundation, which will enable you to build greater levels of control with inCMS (Sitemorse running within CMS) and finally our SMART Content™ capability (intelligent content assessment, the removal of manual issue management and advanced change control - with full workflow).

This recent client statement may be of interest https://sitemorse.com/media/mce_filebrowser/2016/06/13/2016-06-14-sm-pressrelease-lsbu.pdf

Full disclosure: I am an employee of Sitemorse Limited.